# How to show what is needed in retun call and not the whole page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have in my index.php:

```
<?php 
$sContent.='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>'; 
$sContent.='<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>'; 
$sContent.='<script src="in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

$id=2;
$sContent.='<div id="agree">Agree to terms: <input type="checkbox" id="agreed" value=1></div>';
$sContent.='<br><br><div class="show"></div>';

if($_GET['f'] == 'showInfo') 
{
   $sContent.=  'This is the info about item id: '.$_GET['id'];
}

$sAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id."&f=showInfo";
$sDest.= '<br><input class="'.$id.'" type="button" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" value="Click to show info about item '.$id.'" onClick="javascript:showInfo(\''.$sAction.'\');">';

$sContent.=  $sDest;
echo $sContent;
?>
```

And in my js file:

```
function showInfo (action)
{

    var aryAction = action.split('?');
    params = aryAction[1];
    var theUrl = 'index.php';
    alert( aryAction[1]);
    $.ajax ({
        url: theUrl,
        data: params,
        async:true,
        success: function (data, textStatus)
        {
            $('.show').html (data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This shows the whole index.php inside the div with the class 'show'. I don't want thant, I just need 'This is the info about item id: 2' in that div, nothing else.

I've been reading other similar posts and maybe I shouldn't be using the ajax function. Any ideas on how to do it?

Thanks a lot !!

Comment: Can't you just change the php to return only what you want? Alternatively you need to use jQuery to extract that section only after the whole page is received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to separate HTML content from string.

Put both things in an `if` / `else` clause, then it will work:

```
<?php 
$sContent = '';
if($_GET['f'] == 'showInfo') 
{
    $sContent .= 'This is the info about item id: '.$_GET['id'];
}
else
{
    $sContent .= '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>'; 
    $sContent .= '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>'; 
    $sContent .= '<script src="in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>';

    $id=2;
    $sContent .= '<div id="agree">Agree to terms: <input type="checkbox" id="agreed" value=1></div>';
    $sContent .= '<br><br><div class="show"></div>';

    $sAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id."&f=showInfo";
    $sDest .= '<br><input class="'.$id.'" type="button" id="'.$id.'" name="'.$id.'" value="Click to show info about item '.$id.'" onClick="javascript:showInfo(\''.$sAction.'\');">';

    $sContent .= $sDest;
}
echo $sContent;
```